# CSV file is not being written to

Tags: c#, csv, streamwriter

I am trying to write to a CSV file, and have researched a bit on how to do this and it seems pretty straightforward but it is not populating my CSV file when I run it. The program will write to a txt and my console with no issue.

```
    StreamWriter vWriteFile = new StreamWriter("Positions2.csv");

        var path = @"C:\Users\jhochbau\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CsvReader\CSVReader3\Position_2016_02_25.0415.csv";

        if (vShowBoth == false)
        {
            //This determines whether to view by account or by underlying.
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 0 if you wish to see sums by account, or 12 if you wish to see by underlying");
            int vViewControl = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Account" + "  Settle Sum" + " Open Sum" + " Buy Sum" + " Sell Sum");
            using (var parsedLines = File.ReadLines(path).Select(line => line.Split(',')).GetEnumerator())
            {
                bool vMore = parsedLines.MoveNext();
                while (vMore)
                {
                    // Initialize
                    bool vWasSuccessful;
                    var vAccount = parsedLines.Current[vViewControl];
                    double vSettleMMSum = 0;
                    double vOpenSum = 0;
                    int vBuySum = 0;
                    int vSellSum = 0;

                    do
                    {
                        double vParseSettleMM = 0;
                        double vParseOpen = 0;
                        int vParseBuy = 0;
                        int vParseSell = 0;

                        //Parsing data read in from strings, into temp variables
                        vWasSuccessful = double.TryParse(parsedLines.Current[7], out vParseSettleMM);
                        vWasSuccessful = double.TryParse(parsedLines.Current[8], out vParseOpen);
                        vWasSuccessful = int.TryParse(parsedLines.Current[6], out vParseBuy);
                        vWasSuccessful = int.TryParse(parsedLines.Current[10], out vParseSell);

                        //adding temp variabels to sum
                        vSettleMMSum += vParseSettleMM;
                        vOpenSum += vParseOpen;
                        vBuySum += vParseBuy;
                        vSellSum += vParseSell;

                        vMore = parsedLines.MoveNext();
                    }
                    //sets up when to break
                    while (vMore && vAccount == parsedLines.Current[vViewControl]);

                    //After each Break need to print out Account name and sums from above.
                    // Do printing here as part of the loop, at the very end of the loop code block.
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");

                    Console.WriteLine(vAccount + "  " + vSettleMMSum + "  " + vOpenSum + "   " + vBuySum + " " +
                        vSellSum);

                    //vWriteFile.Write(vAccount + "," + vSettleMMSum + "," + vOpenSum + "," + vBuySum + "," +
                    //   vSellSum);

                    vWriteFile.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", vAccount, vSettleMMSum, vOpenSum, vBuySum, vSellSum);

                    //reset sums for next loop
                    vSettleMMSum = 0;
                    vOpenSum = 0;
                    vBuySum = 0;
                    vSellSum = 0;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are not closing nor flushing the stream, unless you terminate your app you will not see the results without closing the stream.

Comment: yep, caught it right after posting this.  Side question, is there a way to skip or consume the first line here:
using (var parsedLines = File.ReadLines(path).Select(line => line.Split(',')).GetEnumerator())

Comment: File.ReadLines(path).Skip(1).Select(line => line.Split(',')).GetEnumerator())

Answer (score 0):

You should make it a habit to wrap your streams with the `using` keyword so you don't run into situations where you forget to close it out. It's a good practice to use the `using` keyword around anything that inherits `IDisposable`

So your code would look like this.

```
using(StreamWriter vWriteFile = new StreamWriter("Positions2.csv"))
{
        var path = @"C:\Users\jhochbau\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\CsvReader\CSVReader3\Position_2016_02_25.0415.csv";

        if (vShowBoth == false)
        {
            //This determines whether to view by account or by underlying.
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter 0 if you wish to see sums by account, or 12 if you wish to see by underlying");
            int vViewControl = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Account" + "  Settle Sum" + " Open Sum" + " Buy Sum" + " Sell Sum");
            using (var parsedLines = File.ReadLines(path).Select(line => line.Split(',')).GetEnumerator())
            {
                bool vMore = parsedLines.MoveNext();
                while (vMore)
                {
                    // Initialize
                    bool vWasSuccessful;
                    var vAccount = parsedLines.Current[vViewControl];
                    double vSettleMMSum = 0;
                    double vOpenSum = 0;
                    int vBuySum = 0;
                    int vSellSum = 0;

                    do
                    {
                        double vParseSettleMM = 0;
                        double vParseOpen = 0;
                        int vParseBuy = 0;
                        int vParseSell = 0;

                        //Parsing data read in from strings, into temp variables
                        vWasSuccessful = double.TryParse(parsedLines.Current[7], out vParseSettleMM);
                        vWasSuccessful = double.TryParse(parsedLines.Current[8], out vParseOpen);
                        vWasSuccessful = int.TryParse(parsedLines.Current[6], out vParseBuy);
                        vWasSuccessful = int.TryParse(parsedLines.Current[10], out vParseSell);

                        //adding temp variabels to sum
                        vSettleMMSum += vParseSettleMM;
                        vOpenSum += vParseOpen;
                        vBuySum += vParseBuy;
                        vSellSum += vParseSell;

                        vMore = parsedLines.MoveNext();
                    }
                    //sets up when to break
                    while (vMore && vAccount == parsedLines.Current[vViewControl]);

                    //After each Break need to print out Account name and sums from above.
                    // Do printing here as part of the loop, at the very end of the loop code block.
                    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");

                    Console.WriteLine(vAccount + "  " + vSettleMMSum + "  " + vOpenSum + "   " + vBuySum + " " +
                        vSellSum);

                    //vWriteFile.Write(vAccount + "," + vSettleMMSum + "," + vOpenSum + "," + vBuySum + "," +
                    //   vSellSum);

                    vWriteFile.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", vAccount, vSettleMMSum, vOpenSum, vBuySum, vSellSum);

                    //reset sums for next loop
                    vSettleMMSum = 0;
                    vOpenSum = 0;
                    vBuySum = 0;
                    vSellSum = 0;

                }
            }
        }
}
```